# How to have a comma most distinct from a prime

Tags: punctuation

At times, students in some introductory classes mistake the comma after an equation for a prime. This occurs for example if the comma shows up after a fraction, in which case the student thinks it is a prime on the denominator of that fraction.

The display and MWE  in  [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50161/vertical-position-of-punctuation-following-fractions-in-display-style-equations) shows comma vs prime and  it appears that using the Palatino font makes the issue worse, as in comparison with the Euler font. There, the remedy that is sought is to raise the location of comma after a fraction.

My question is  in what font will comma look most distinct from a prime? For example a comma looking like a semi circle might be better for such situations.

A modified version of above MWE is reproduced below.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% To use Palatino
\usepackage{mathpazo}                   
% To use  Euler
%\usepackage[small, euler-digits]{eulervm}  

 \begin{document}
 Question: which font accentuates the difference between prime and comma most?

 Example 1. Comma after fraction vs prime on  denominator

 \begin{equation}
 a = \frac{1}{A+B}, \qquad b = \frac{1}{A+B'}
 \end{equation}

 Example 2 : prime on left side of case with comma after the case

 \begin{equation*}
 \left\{\begin{matrix}
 x'&= 3x-2y \\
 y'&= 2x-2y \end{matrix}\right. , 
 \end{equation*}

 \end{document}
```

[image: The resulting PDF]

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}` that we can compile that shows the problem. Shouldn`t a mathematical prime symbol be coded as a `\prime` which looks nothing like a comma.?

Comment: @PeterWilson Please check the linked reference.

Comment: You ask about the graphic of a comma being distinguishable from the graphic of a prime. Your linked reference does not deal with this; just the location of the graphic, not the look of the graphic.

Comment: It's often recommended to insert a thin space `\,` between the fraction and the comma.  (Some authors always place a thin space before a final comma in a line of a math display.)

Comment: @PeterWilson  An MWE is included.

Comment: I'd simply omit the comma; the space already separates the two  fractions and a comma adds nothing to clarity. And I'd *never* use punctuation after `cases` or a similar object.

Comment: @egreg Dropping the comma seems to be the simplest solution. However the issue comes up in standard math homework software such as WebAssign too.